# Screen Casting starts but only thumbnail is visible and unable to play video in android 11

Tags: android, screen-capture, screen-recording

I'm working on a screen recorder app where if app is in backstack on android 11 and on starting of screen recording only screen casting option is visible but "app is using microphone"  message is  not displayed and on stopping recording only shows thumbnail and video is not played as video size is too small this is my recording code and this error is only occuring in android 11 OS other are working fine

```
public void startRecording() {
        synchronized (sSync) {
            Log.i(TAG, "startRecording: inside synchronized");
            if (mMuxer == null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "startRecording: muxer is null");
                getScreenSize();
                mMediaProjection = mMediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(mScreenCaptureResultCode, mScreenCaptureIntent);
                DisplayManager dm = (DisplayManager) Objects.requireNonNull(MyApplication.Companion.getApplication()).getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
                Display defaultDisplay;
                if (dm != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "startRecording: dim is not null");
                    defaultDisplay = dm.getDisplay(Display.DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot display manager?!?");
                }
                if (defaultDisplay == null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("No display found.");
                }


                try {
                    mMuxer = new MediaMuxerWrapper(context, ".mp4");    // if you record audio only, ".m4a" is also OK.
                    if (true) {
                        VideoSetting videoSetting = SettingManager.getVideoProfile(context);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Video config: " + videoSetting);
                        mCurrentVideoSetting = videoSetting;
                        List<RenderUtil.CustomDecorator> decors = createDecorators();
//                         new TestMediaScreenEncoderHard(mMuxer, mMediaEncoderListener, mMediaProjection, mCurrentVideoSetting, mScreenDensity, decors);

                        if (MyUtils.isRunningOnEmulator()) {
                            new MediaScreenEncoder(mMuxer, mMediaEncoderListener, mMediaProjection, mCurrentVideoSetting, mScreenDensity, decors);
                        } else {
                            new MediaScreenEncoderHard(mMuxer, mMediaEncoderListener, mMediaProjection, mCurrentVideoSetting, mScreenDensity, decors);
                        }
                    }

                    if (true) {
                        // for audio capturing
                        new MediaAudioEncoder(mMuxer, mMediaEncoderListener);
                        Log.i(TAG, "startRecording: audio capture");
                    }
                    mMuxer.prepare();
                    mMuxer.startRecording();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "startScreenRecord:", e);
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my media encoder class

```
public class MediaAudioEncoder extends MediaEncoder {
    public static final int SAMPLES_PER_FRAME = 1024;    // AAC, bytes/frame/channel
    public static final int FRAMES_PER_BUFFER = 25;    // AAC, frame/buffer/sec
    private static final String TAG = MediaAudioEncoder.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String MIME_TYPE = "audio/mp4a-latm";
    private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;    // 44.1[KHz] is only setting guaranteed to be available on all devices.
    private static final int BIT_RATE = 64000;
    private static final int[] AUDIO_SOURCES = new int[]{
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER,
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT,
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION,
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION,
    };
    private AudioThread mAudioThread = null;

    public MediaAudioEncoder(final MediaMuxerWrapper muxer, final MediaEncoderListener listener) {
        super(muxer, listener);
    }

    /**
     * select the first codec that match a specific MIME type
     *
     * @param mimeType
     * @return
     */
    private static final MediaCodecInfo selectAudioCodec(final String mimeType) {
//        if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "selectAudioCodec:");

        MediaCodecInfo result = null;
        // get the list of available codecs
        final int numCodecs = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();
        LOOP:
        for (int i = 0; i < numCodecs; i++) {
            final MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);
            if (!codecInfo.isEncoder()) {    // skipp decoder
                continue;
            }
            final String[] types = codecInfo.getSupportedTypes();
            for (int j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
//                if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "supportedType:" + codecInfo.getName() + ",MIME=" + types[j]);
                if (types[j].equalsIgnoreCase(mimeType)) {
                    if (result == null) {
                        result = codecInfo;
                        break LOOP;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare() throws IOException {
//        if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "prepare:");
        mTrackIndex = -1;
        mMuxerStarted = mIsEOS = false;
        // prepare MediaCodec for AAC encoding of audio data from inernal mic.
        final MediaCodecInfo audioCodecInfo = selectAudioCodec(MIME_TYPE);
        if (audioCodecInfo == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to find an appropriate codec for " + MIME_TYPE);
            return;
        }
//        if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "selected codec: " + audioCodecInfo.getName());

        final MediaFormat audioFormat = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat(MIME_TYPE, SAMPLE_RATE, 1);
        audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC);
        audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_MASK, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO);
        audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, BIT_RATE);
        audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
//        if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "format: " + audioFormat);
        mMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
        mMediaCodec.configure(audioFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        mMediaCodec.start();
//        if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "prepare finishing");
        if (mListener != null) {
            try {
                mListener.onPrepared(this);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "prepare:", e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startRecording() {
        super.startRecording();
        // create and execute audio capturing thread using internal mic
        if (mAudioThread == null) {
            mAudioThread = new AudioThread();
            mAudioThread.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void release() {
        mAudioThread = null;
        super.release();
    }

    /**
     * Thread to capture audio data from internal mic as uncompressed 16bit PCM data
     * and write them to the MediaCodec encoder
     */
    private class AudioThread extends Thread {
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                final int min_buffer_size = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(
                        SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                int buffer_size = SAMPLES_PER_FRAME * FRAMES_PER_BUFFER;
                if (buffer_size < min_buffer_size)
                    buffer_size = ((min_buffer_size / SAMPLES_PER_FRAME) + 1) * SAMPLES_PER_FRAME * 2;

                AudioRecord audioRecord = null;
                for (final int source : AUDIO_SOURCES) {
                    try {
                        audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
                                source, SAMPLE_RATE,
                                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffer_size);
                        if (audioRecord != null) {
                            if (audioRecord.getState() != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
                                audioRecord.release();
                                audioRecord = null;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                        audioRecord = null;
                    }
                    if (audioRecord != null) break;
                }
                if (audioRecord != null) {
                    try {
                        if (mIsEncoding) {
//                            if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "AudioThread:start audio recording");
                            final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(SAMPLES_PER_FRAME);
                            int readBytes;
                            audioRecord.startRecording();
                            try {
                                for (; mIsEncoding && !mRequestStop && !mIsEOS; ) {
                                    // read audio data from internal mic
                                    buf.clear();
                                    readBytes = audioRecord.read(buf, SAMPLES_PER_FRAME);
                                    if (readBytes > 0) {
                                        // set audio data to encoder
                                        buf.position(readBytes);
                                        buf.flip();
                                        encode(buf, readBytes, getPTSUs());
                                        frameAvailableSoon();
                                    }
                                }
                                frameAvailableSoon();
                            } finally {
                                audioRecord.stop();
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        audioRecord.release();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "failed to initialize AudioRecord");
                }
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "AudioThread#run", e);
            }
//            if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "AudioThread:finished");
        }
    }

}
```

These are my error logs

> 2022-06-09 09:40:56.785 21415-21616/com.example.recorderscreen
> E/IAudioFlinger: createRecord returned error -1 2022-06-09
> 09:40:56.785 21415-21616/com.example.recorderscreen E/AudioRecord:
> createRecord_l(436738312): AudioFlinger could not create record track,
> status: -1 2022-06-09 09:40:56.785
> 21415-21616/com.example.recorderscreen E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error
> creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status
> -1. 2022-06-09 09:40:56.785 21415-21616/com.example.recorderscreen E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native
> AudioRecord object. 2022-06-09 09:40:56.785
> 21415-21616/com.example.recorderscreen E/MediaAudioEncoder: failed to
> initialize AudioRecord

Comment: can you please share the error log as well of Android 11

Comment: @RobinHood just updated my question kindly check it out

Comment: i am not able to see the code where you are saving files in physical storage. did you try this on android 12?

Comment: @RobinHood I'm using targetSdkVersion 31 and tested on android 12 where it's working fine... The issue is only on android 11

Comment: Storage access is changed from android 11 you cannot save file using old method. Read more detail here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage